# Can’t get server to set up network with netplan

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan, mediaserver

Coming from Ubuntu server 16.04 I flashed my server and put 18 on it and didn’t realize they changed the way networking happens on the server. I have been using ifupdown forever now Ubuntu is now using netplan I have tried to get the config file made up but every time I run netplan try it says error has occurred on the line of the interface eno1. any help would be appreciated. I’d love to go back to ifupdown but can’t because i can’t get the network connected. Also every time I run a ping it’s failing to get the ip from dns but still shows on startup how many packages can be updated.

This is how I have my config file written

```
network:
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
         eno1:
        addresses: []
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
        version: 2
```

I am editing the file I found in /etc/netplan
It is named 50-cloud-init.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netplan configuration files use YAML.  YAML is extremely indent-sensitive, and if anything is not indented properly, or not where it needs to be in order for the YAML to be parsed by netplan, you will get errors like this.

You have mismatched indents and a few things that are not in the proper location (per https://netplan.io/examples and the Netplan examples for DHCP addressing).

Try using this instead:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know what happens. Thank you

Comment: Just got it working thank you Sir you are a gentleman and a scholar.